# ReactJs format a long string with break tags but aswell color some words of the string

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

in ReactJs, my goal is to format a long string with `<br/>`, thing that i have achieved using a bit of JavaScript like this:

My long string:

> export const fadeAnimation = { \n initial: {opacity: 0, transition: { ...transition, delay: 0.5 }, }, \n animate: { opacity: 1, transition: { ...transition, delay: 0.3 },  }, \n  exit: {opacity: 0,    transition: { ...transition, delay: 0 }, \n }

My javascript works fine to add `<br/>` where i've put `\n` :

```js
const formatText = (text) => {
        const finalMessage = text.split('\n').map((item, index, row) => {
        if(index == 0 || index + 1 === row.length ){  
        return (
          <div key={index} style={{color:"rgb(166, 154, 154)"}}>
            {item}
            <br/>
          </div>
        )}else{
        return (
            <div key={index} style={{marginLeft:"20px", color:"rgb(166, 154, 154)"}}>
              {item}
              <br/>
            </div>
        )}})
        return finalMessage
      }
```

But i would like to color some of the words inside the string like "Export" or "const" or "fadeAnimation" and so on..
I know i can add `<span>` to style those words but actually i dont know how to add them since i'm mapping over my splitted string to add other things.
Any help would be grateful THANKS!

Comment: Is that string coming from somewhere? Is it dynamic or a constant string?

Comment: It is a constant string that comes from "../config/constants.js" i've created for all the constant textes i have in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

1. Store the markup directly in the constant.
2. Store the string along with the associated HTML tags in the constant.

**Storing the markup directly**

The constant will look like this:

```
const fadeAnimation = [
  <span className="export-keyword">export</span>,
  <span className="const-keyword">const</span>,
  <span className="const-name">fadeAnimation</span>,
  ...
];
```

And you can render the array directly in your component:

```
return fadeAnimation;
```

In React, if you return an array in your component, it will render each element from the array.

**Storing an array of object**

The constant will look like this:

```
const fadeAnimation = [
  { type: 'export', text: 'export' }
  { type: 'constant', text: 'const' }
  ...
];
```

And in your render method:

```
return fadeAnimation.map(el => {
  switch (el.type) {
    case 'export':
      return <span className="export">{el.text}</span>;
    case 'constant':
      return <span className="constant">{el.text}</span>;
    ...
  }
});
```

The above code snippets are just examples so you will need to work on actually making them work, but the idea is to render each piece of your string with a specific HTML tag so that you can style them differently.